# Convergence of series of random variables converging in probability

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, probability-limit-theorems

Let $X_{j,t}$ be a double-indexed sequence of random variables whose sample average over the $t$'s converges to the constant $\alpha_j$. Assume further that the $\alpha_j$'s are summable:

$$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{t =1}^{N}X_{j, t} \xrightarrow[]{p}\alpha_j,  \text{ and } \sum_{j =1}^{\infty}\alpha_j = \alpha$$

Does this imply the following, as $N\rightarrow\infty$?

$$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{j =1}^{2^N}\sum_{t =1}^{N}X_{j, t} \xrightarrow[]{p}\alpha$$

My hunch says yes, though I'm not sure. Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no.

Let $S_{j,N}=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{t =1}^{N}X_{j, t}$ and $A_{j,N}=\{\omega:|S_{j,N}-\alpha_j|>\epsilon_j\}$. Then $\lim_{N\to\infty}P(A_{j,N})=0$. But 
$$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{j =1}^{2^N}\sum_{t =1}^{N}X_{j, t} =\sum_{j =1}^{2^N}S_{j,N}\xrightarrow[]{p}\alpha$$
means 
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty}P\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^{2^N}A_{j,N}\right)=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{2^N}P(A_{j,N})=0
$$
for $A_{j,N}$ are disjoint. This is clearly not true if $P(A_{j,N})=\dfrac1{N}$.

However we can prove that if 
$$
\frac{1}{N}\sum_{t =1}^{N}X_{j, t}\xrightarrow[]{a.s}\alpha_j
$$
Then
$$
\frac{1}{N}\sum_{j =1}^{2^N}\sum_{t =1}^{N}X_{j, t} \xrightarrow[]{a.s}\alpha
$$
Let $A_{j,N}=\{\omega:|S_{j,N}-\alpha_j|>\epsilon_j\}$. Since for any $N$, $P(A_{j,N})=0$
$$
P\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^{2^N}A_{j,N}\right)\leqslant \sum_{j=1}^{2^N}P(A_{j,N})=0
$$
Hence 
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty}P\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^{2^N}A_{j,N}\right)=0
$$